# getting the server's certificate when InitializeSecurityContext fails with SEC_E_WRONG_PRINCIPAL

Tags: schannel

InitializeSecurityContext (Schannel) fails with SEC_E_WRONG_PRINCIPAL when none of the names on the server's supplied certificate match the pszTargetName parameter, which is the name of the server, essentially.

If you have a fully formed security context, you can get the server's certificate with a call to QueryContextAttributes for SECPKG_ATTR_REMOTE_CERT_CONTEXT. The call to QueryContextAttributes fails with SEC_E_INVALID_HANDLE if the partly formed security context from the failing InitializeSecurityContext negotiation is used as the phContext parameter.

In this case, is there a way for the client side to get access to the certificate the server sent so we can report the names on the certificate?

NB. If we *really really* wanted to, we could probably redo the negotiation, specifying ISC_REQ_MANUAL_CRED_VALIDATION, and then call QueryContextAttributes on *that* security context (and then immediately destroy it), but this seems stupid.

Answer (score 0):

You can try specifying `SCH_CRED_NO_SERVERNAME_CHECK` in the `SCH_CREDENTIALS.dwFlags`. You may have to combine with `SCH_CRED_SNI_CREDENTIAL`. However, then you'd have to abort the connection by sending a TLS alert in your code after checking the name. These links may be helpful:
https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio-tls/issues/32

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0b7e3858-00ef-41f9-8772-dd1896e519ac/how-to-add-sni-client-hello-extension-using-schannel-api

Otherwise, if you're looking to do this inline, you may have to resort to manual ASN.1 parsing of the received data to look for the certificate as you Negotiate manually. This function may be of use: `CertCreateCertificateContext` .

Comment: Yep, that's another way of working around the issue, thanks.